# In story mode how do I change my team to attack mode?

Tags: rainbow-six-vegas-2

They are stuck in "Infiltrate" mode and won't attack anyone! I know there's a way to change them back to attack mode, but I tried Google for like 20 minutes but all I get are junk websites!

Comment: This question is already tagged with [rainbow-6-vegas-2], there's no need for the name to be in the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change ROE (Rules of Engagement) Press the back button for Xbox and select for PS3

Source: http://uk.faqs.ign.com/articles/861/861810p1.html  (Section 2 - Controls)

Answer (score 4):

You're referring to the "rules of engagement" system. It has been a while since I played the game, so I can't remember the default key for changing it, but you can check in the options menu.

I believe the HUD color will change from red (shoot on sight) to grey (return fire) depending on your current rules of engagement.